# Comparing two exponential random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent random variables drawn from the exponential distribution with parameters $\lambda_A<\lambda_B$. What is the probability that $A<B$?

I'm of course aware of the probability density function and the cumulative distribution function of the [exponential random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), but I'm not sure how to use it to answer this question. Also, there seems to be no such formula on the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since $A$ and $B$ are independent, their joint density is:
$$p(a, b) = \lambda_A\lambda_Be^{-(\lambda_Aa+\lambda_Bb)}$$

In general, if we have a joint density $p(a, b)$ defined on non-negative reals, we want the probability that $B$ can take any value $[0,\infty]$ and that $A$ can take any value $[0,B]$:
$$P(A < B) = \int_0^\infty \int_0^b p(a, b) da db$$
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
   P(A < B) &=& \int_0^\infty \int_0^b p(a, b) da db \\
            &=& \int_0^\infty \lambda_B e^{-\lambda_Bb} \int_0^b \lambda_A e^{-\lambda_Aa} da db \\
&=& \int_0^\infty \lambda_B e^{-\lambda_Bb} (1 - e^{-\lambda_Ab}) db \\
&=& \int_0^\infty \lambda_B e^{-\lambda_Bb} db - \int_0^\infty \lambda_B e^{-(\lambda_A + \lambda_B)b} db \\
&=& 1 - \frac{\lambda_B}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B} \\
&=& \frac{\lambda_A}{\lambda_A + \lambda_B} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Why do we know this equation for $P(A<B)$ in your second equation?

Comment: Given a joint density $p(a, b)$, the probability of a set E occurring is given by integrating over that set: $\int_{(a, b) \in E} p(a, b) da db$.  Since these are non-negative random variables, $B$ can take any non-negative value (i.e. it is in $[0, \infty]$).  Then the set such that $A < B$ are all those values of $A$ from $0$ up to a particular $b$.  The outer integral is with respect to $db$ which is free to go from $0$ to $\infty$, but the inner one is restricted to go from $0$ to $b$ (for each possible $b$).

Comment: For clarity, I could just as well have written $P(A<B) = \int_0^\infty \int_a^\infty p(a,b) db da$.

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
Pr(A\leq B)
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_B(y)Pr(A\leq y)dy\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda_B e^{-\lambda_B y}(1-e^{-\lambda_A y})dy\\
&=\frac{\lambda_A}{\lambda_A+\lambda_B}
\end{align}
$$