# Probability that two tosses of an exponentially distributed variable will give same value

Tags: probability

This question is related to
[Comparing two exponential random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332413/comparing-two-exponential-random-variables) except that I am interested in calculating the probability that $A = B$ and given $\lambda_a  = \lambda_b = \lambda$. I tried calculating it as $\int_0^\inf f(x).f(x) dx$ where $f(x)$ is pdf of exponentially distributed variable, which gives me answer as $\lambda / 2$ but this does not pass the smell test for me. I would expect answer to be independent of $\lambda$ since $\lambda$ is not dimensionless whereas the answer should be dimensionless.

Comment: Were you expecting the answer $0$?

Comment: If a real-value random variable has a continuous distribution with no atoms (discrete values with non-zero probabilities), then the probability that two samples will be equal is $0$.

Comment: Ah. I see. I think you are correct.

Comment: However, your result does tell you that the probability that the two values are within some small range $\varepsilon$ of each other is approximately equal to $\frac\lambda2 \varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot my fundamentals