# Given Density Of Independent Random Variable $Y$ And $W$ ,Find $P(Y>W)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> Let $Y$ and $W$ are independent random variable with PDF
> $$f_Y(y)=\begin{cases}
> \frac13~e^{\frac {-y}{3}}& y\geq0\\~\\
> 0&\text{else}
> \end{cases}$$
> $$f_W(w)=\begin{cases}
> \frac14~e^{\frac {-w}{4}}& w\geq0\\~\\
> 0&\text{else}
> \end{cases}$$
> Find $P(Y>W)$.

Define $Z=Y+(-W)$ and we find  $P(Z>0)$.
Using substitution I find density of $-W$ as
$$f_{(-W)}(w)=\begin{cases}
\frac14~e^{\frac {w}{4}}& w\leq0\\~\\
0&\text{else}
\end{cases}$$ And using convolution I find density of $Z$ as
$$f_Z(z)=\begin{cases}
\frac17~e^{\frac {z}{4}}& z\leq0\\~\\
\frac17~e^{\frac {-z}{3}}& z\geq0
\end{cases}$$Now
$$\begin{align}
P(Z>0)&=\int\limits_{(0,\infty)} f_Z(z)~dz\\~\\
&=\int\limits_{(0,\infty)}\frac17~e^{\frac {-z}{3}}~dz\\~\\
&=\frac37
\end{align}$$

This answer is given in options ,I don't have answer key though. Is my calculation correct?
Even if it is I think there is another easy way to find $P(Y>W)$.

Please share other approaches to solve this question.

Comment: Looks correct. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332413/comparing-two-exponential-random-variables